# Cannot add constraint check with function call in Mariadb

Tags: mariadb, constraints

I am using Mariadb 10.4.10 on Ubuntu 18.04, and the tool client is DBeaver 6.2.5

I want to make full use of the Constraint Check feature in Mariadb to ensure data integrity, since it is enforced starting from 10.2.1.

However, whenever I try to add a new constraint into an existing table, it gives me an error.

The query I tried is something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mydb.users ADD CONSTRAINT `username_minlen`
  CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(username) >= 6);
```

and the error message is like this:

> SQL Error [4025] [23000]: (conn=47) CONSTRAINT `username_minlen` failed for `mydb`.`users`

My guess is that that `CHAR_LENGTH` is the cause of the problem, because when I ran the query like this one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mydb.users ADD CONSTRAINT `username_no_empty_str`
  CHECK (username <> '');
```

this worked just fine.

I was wondering if I cannot call at all any function or procedure inside the `CHECK` expression, but googling on this showed me no satisfactory answers, most of them relating to other SQL systems than Mariadb.

Is calling functions syntactically impossible in Mariadb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check if you have data that violates it:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mydb`.`users`
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(username) < 6;
```

Then update it:

```
UPDATE `mydb`.`users`
SET username = ?
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(username) < 6;
```

And finally apply check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.users ADD CONSTRAINT `username_minlen` CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(username) >= 6);
```

Comment: Wow, I never realized that even existing records could affect new constraints about to be added... Really appreciated your answer.